# White Space appears before an image on local machine but not in jsFiddle

Tags: html, css

Why does white space appear to the left of my image on my local machine, when it does not in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq48L/4/)?

I'm running the same code there is in the fiddle, but the fiddle works fine, while on my local machine there is a bit of space to the left of the image. Notice how the left is wider than the right.

How can I fix this? I'm using the same image on my local machine as well as my fiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>The annoying image</title>

 <style>
.outer {
    border:1px solid #ddd; 
    float:left; 
    height:150px; 
    padding:10px; 
}

.outer img {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
.outer:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="outer">
    <img src="/imgur/us/thumb_2.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JSFiddle for me**

[image]

**Local machine**

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ldyqNz0.png

Comment: I see the gap in your fiddle too.

Comment: See my updated question with what I see in the fiddle and my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::before` pseudo-element acts like a real element in many ways, and respecting the rules of whitespace is one of them:

```
<div class="outer">
    ::before
    <img src="/imgur/us/thumb_2.jpg">
</div>
```

The `::before` is inserted at the immediate beginning of the element (the space between `>` and `:` there is just for presentation), and there’s whitespace between it and your image because of the newline and indentation.

If you remove it, [there will be no gap](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq48L/8/).

```
<div class="outer"><img src="/imgur/us/thumb_2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot believe this thing was being caused by the img being on a new line? Is that the problem?

Comment: @Norman: And having indentation, yes. The whitespace exists, but it doesn’t matter until it’s between elements or you apply some kind of `white-space` rule.